# Network logs support with karate UI framework?

Tags: karate

I want to access and store the network logs from the browser for one of my UI test, can we achieve this with karate UI framework.

Comment: You can, but you may need to do some research. Here is a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63243328/143475